# KTX2 Textures For GLB in react-three/fiber

Tags: reactjs, react-three-fiber

I am trying to load a glb that has ktx2 textures. It seems to indicate it can't load the textures, but I'm not sure where it's trying to load them from since they're part of the glb and that is being referenced with the right path.

Sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/performance-scaling-forked-06w623?file=/src/App.js)

The facecap.glb file is the example one from threejs itself, [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/models/gltf/facecap.glb)

Relevant code:

```
import { Suspense } from 'react'
import { useLoader, Canvas } from '@react-three/fiber'
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader'
import { KTX2Loader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/KTX2Loader'
import { MeshoptDecoder } from 'three/examples/jsm/libs/meshopt_decoder.module.js'
import faceUrl from './facecap.glb'

function FaceModel() {
  const result = useLoader(GLTFLoader, faceUrl, (loader) => {
    const ktxLoader = new KTX2Loader()
    ktxLoader.setTranscoderPath('three/examples/js/libs/basis/')
    loader.setKTX2Loader(ktxLoader)
    loader.setMeshoptDecoder(MeshoptDecoder)
  })
  return <primitive object={result} />
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Suspense fallback={null}>
      <Canvas>
        <FaceModel />
      </Canvas>
    </Suspense>
  )
}
```

Comment: Been trying the exact same thing. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to use KTX2 files inside of React three Fiber is to use [useKTX2](https://github.com/pmndrs/drei#usektx2) hook from `@react-three/drei` like below

```js
import {useKTX2} from "@react-three/drei";
const texture = useKTX2(url)
const [texture1, texture2] = useKTX2([texture1, texture2])

return <meshStandardMaterial map={texture} />
```

As for your case what I'd suggest is to just export your glb without any texture. Generate the React three fiber boilerplate code from [gltf.pmnd.rs](https://gltf.pmnd.rs) and apply the texture by above method.

Comment: What's the use of [texture1, texture2] in this example?

Comment: If you want to use multiple ktx2 texture, use that array method.